# Get the HTTP body response of a POST with volley-android

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am trying to get in my app some data and show to the user by using an HTTP POST request with Volley.
My issue is that I don't know how to get the server Body response to the request. In the code below the response is always "200" which turns to be the HTTP status code.

How can I extract the body response and manage as a string?

```
 RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    final String requestBody = Utility.toCorrectCase(req);
    //Decommentare solo per il debug
    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),requestBody, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i("VOLLEY", response);
            Bitmap myBitmap = QRCode.from(response).bitmap();
            qrcode.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = qrcode.getLayoutParams();
            params.width =  qrDisplayedSize;
            params.height = qrDisplayedSize;
            qrcode.setLayoutParams(params);
            loadingText.setText(getString(R.string.prod_id_desc).concat(response));
            qrcode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            backButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("VOLLEY", error.toString());
            new SweetAlertDialog(getApplicationContext(), SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE)
                    .setTitleText("Errore comunicazione server")
                    .setContentText("Qualcosa non ha funzionato!\nDescrizione errore:".concat(error.toString()))
                    .show();
            finish();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            try {
                return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            String responseString;
            responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);

            return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Whats your response looks like?

Comment: As i write above my response is a string " 200", it should be a string like "Ok updated"

Comment: 200 is StatusCode. You are saying your response body is empty and you want to display the message to user (OK Updated) when you have 200 Status Code? Or your saying your response body is 200 and also your status Code is 200?

Comment: The second one, and I'm expecting a different result (I've tested the server with postman and the answer should be "OK")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After days of searches, I've found out that I have not overridden correctly the networkResponse. So for everyone with my same trouble, the answer of my question is: parseNetworkResponse must be overridden to get response body in an easisest way.

```
            @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

            if(response.statusCode==400){
                new SweetAlertDialog(getApplicationContext(), SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE)
                        .setTitleText("Errore comunicazione server")
                        .setContentText("Qualcosa non ha funzionato!\nCodice errore:"+response.statusCode)
                        .show();
                finish();
            }
            return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

change this it works for me

```
@Override
    protected Response < String > parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

     String parsed;
     try {
      parsed = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
     } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      parsed = new String(response.data);
     }
     return Response.success(parsed, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));

    }
```