# volley response was not getting any data

Tags: android, android-volley

when am using the following code to call a post service in a volley but I used getting a response as

> E/VOLLEY: com.android.volley.NetworkResponse@3d5dc44

```
 try {
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            String URL = "url";

         final   String requestBody = "mutation M {" + "logIn" + "(" +
                    "countryCode:" + "\"" + "1" + "\"" +
                    "deviceType:" + "\"" + "Android" + "\"" + 
                    "osVerison:" + "\"" + "5.1.1" + "\"" +
                    "appVerison:" + "\"" + "2.9" + "\"" +
                    "currentCountry:" + "\"" + "IND" + "\"" +
                    "language:" + "\"" + "ENG" + "\"" +
                    "deviceModal:" + "\"" + "ASUS" + "" +

                    "\")" + "{_id,countryCode,phoneNumber,emailAddress,profilePic}";


            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e("VOLLEY", response);
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
                }
            }) {


                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("Cache-Control","no-cache");
                    params.put("Content-type", "application/graphql");
                    return params;
                }
                @Override
                public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                    try {
                        return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                        VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                    String responseString = "";
                    if (response != null) {
                        responseString = response.toString();
                        // can get more details such as response.headers
                    }
                    return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                }
            };

            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

i am new to volley please help me same thing i worked with retrofit but i want to use in volley.

Comment: Can you send the URL you're using for the request. ?

Comment: i found the solution and i have posted there https://stackoverflow.com/a/45959384/6749161

Answer (score 0):

I have modified this code and working for me i have found this from the super method of parseNetworkResponse

```
@Override
    protected Response < String > parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

     String parsed;
     try {
      parsed = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
     } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      parsed = new String(response.data);
     }
     return Response.success(parsed, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));

    }
```